# Force VS C++ compiler to run code in RELEASE mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to profile a particular function but find that in release mode the compiler (quite correctly!) decides to remove my useless timing code:

```
DWORD dwStart = GetTickCount();
DWORD dwTmp = 0;
for (int nLoop=0; nLoop<1000; nLoop++)
    dwTmp = SomeFunction();

DWORD dwElapsed = (GetTickCount() - dwStart);
LogTime(dwElapsed);
```

This works fine in DEBUG mode (if I change the loop to 2000, then it takes about twice as long). Is there a simple trick or local compiler switch I can use to temporarily trick or force the compiler into running this code in RELEASE mode?

Comment: are you sure it's not just `LogTime` that isn't doing anything when `DEBUG` is not defined  (or similaR)

Comment: Yes, quite sure. If I pop up a message box instead of logging it I get the same behaviour. The compiler is (cleverly) optimising out my code in RELEASE mode.

Comment: I do not think the compiler can remove your code - the `GetTickCount()` call might have side effects it does not know about. So it is likely `LogTime` issue as Rowland suggested

Comment: What exactly is the behaviour you're observing? No log/popup or you see dwElapsed of zero?

Comment: Well, if I pop up a message with the timing information using MessageBox(...) I get the same behaviour. The compiler is definitely removing the code (see answer using #pragma optimize).

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin: You get a small value for dwElapsed which does not change as the size of the loop is increased, though it does in DEBUG mode. As pointed out, this is because the compiler optimises out the loop. If I turn off optimisation (as per answer below), it works as expected (ie. dwElapsed increases as the size of the loop increases). Am interested in learning if there are other tricks I can use in future so that when I delete my temporary test code, I don't also have to remember to delete the #pragmas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pragma optimize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx).

However, this seems to be a strange problem to want to solve.
What are your exact intentions?

Comment: Thanks that works, put "#pragma optimize( "", off )" before the function containing the timing code and "#pragma optimize( "", on )" afterwards. Not quite what I'm looking for, though, because it removes optimisation from the entire function...but more importantly I run the risk of accidentally forgetting to delete the pragmas after deleting my temporary code!

Comment: You can wrap the pragma in an `#ifdef`. The compiler determines that `SomeFunction()` has no side-effects, so it can safely apply that optimizaion. You asked for tricking the compiler to run the code always in release mode, not debug mode. If you meant it the other way around, you could declare `dwTmp` as *volatile*, as @FourtyTwo suggested. Are you sure you got the question right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only running those lines in **RELEASE mode** and rest of the source in **DEBUG mode**, as far as I know there is no such thing, If you just want to run your whole source in **RELEASE mode** and don't know how to, follow these;

At the top of the Visual Studio **click BUILD** To the down **click Configuration Manager** change your project's configuration to **Relase** and click close.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to declare dwTmp as volatile: This way, the compiler is not allowed to remove the assignments to this variable.

Comment: That would force the code to run in `debug mode`, as the OP put it. Running the code in `release mode` would imply optimizing the loop away, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int nLoop=0; nLoop<1000; nLoop++)
    dwTmp = SomeFunction();
```

If the function `SomeFunction` is simple, and the compiler can guess its return value, the loop will be eliminated by compiler, and **only** following statement would be there:

```
dwTmp = SomeFunction();
```

Generally programmers use timing and other profiling on long executing function to find out which part of program is taking time/memory/locks. You are trying something very different.

Comment: Yes, that's true (and this was noted in the question itself). But how to stop the compiler from eliminating the loop in RELEASE mode? The compiler should do all its clever optimisation in RELEASE mode everywhere else except my temporary timing code (when I'd like it do do exactly what I ask).

Comment: Try: `C/C++ -> Optimization -> Optimization -> Disabled`

Comment: True that is possible, but then optimisation is turned off across the entire application (and I might as well run the code in DEBUG mode). I'd like to run the function N times in RELEASE mode, with optimisation enabled everywhere else. Seems like the best answer so far is to use #pragma optimize (@namezero), though this is not ideal because one might forget to remove the preprocessor directives! :o)

Comment: You do the same thing for specific file. You cannot do that for specific function, or a code snippet (from VS project settings).